# SQL - MySQL - How to get only records which have the same value of one of columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the table `messages` with the following columns:

`client`, `message`, `type`

*Without primary key*.

`type` could be `A`, `B`, `C`.

**How can I get all clients which have message of the same type only?**

*For example*:

*Alex hello C
Alex Hello C
Robert Hello B
Robert Hello C

Result:
Alex*

Comment: can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: It's the part of bigger query. I've tried something like SELECT client, max(type), min(type) FROM messages GROUP BY client HAVING max(type) = min(type). It doesn't work, I need some hints

Comment: That query works fine https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5CSw2JDVMcV3qmvumCCwzV/0

Comment: Do you mean "How can I get only clients which have multiple messages of the same type?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you already tried works fine to me, but here is another way of achieving it.

```
SELECT client
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT client, type
    FROM messages
) as temp
GROUP BY client
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Client, Type
from messages
group by Client, Type
having count(*) > 1;
```